# Receiving "undefined" errors when trying to access object details

Tags: javascript

I'm very much a beginner when it comes to javascript, so I hope that you will bear with me.

I have an html file that contains a table with three values for reporting on a variety of system statuses - name, status, and notes.  I am pulling the contents of the table into a variable, and scanning it for  tags that point to an offline or partially online system.  If found, the system name, status, and any notes concerning its status are stored into an object array (at least, I think it is an object array - I'm new at this).

Here's where I am having trouble.  While I am looping through the table looking for a matching  value, I am able to display an alert with the appropriate information as it is assigned to the object (example **SmartPay, Offline, Not taking credit cards**).  Once I am out of the loop, I am unable to reference any data that I have stored.  Here's the object constructor and function that I am working with:

```
function status(name, status, notes) {
  this.name = name;
  this.status = status;
  this.notes = notes;
}

function parseStatus() {
  var tagMatch = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var problemStatus = new Array();
  var j = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < tagMatch.length; i++) {  
    if (tagMatch[i].textContent == "Offline" || 
    tagMatch[i].textContent == "Partially Online") {
      problemStatus[j] = new status(tagMatch[i-1].textContent,   
      tagMatch[i].textContent, tagMatch[i+1].textContent);

    alert("OFFLINE: " + problemStatus[j]['name'] + ", " + 
    problemStatus[j]['status'] + ", " + problemStatus[j]['notes']);

    j++;
    }
  }
}
```

The alert at the end of the for loop displays everything correctly.  If I add this after the end bracket for the loop

```
alert(problemStatus[0]['name']);
```

I get "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

I do not understand where I am going wrong.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Edited to include the link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donfrankrice/jsyo4evr/)

Comment: Please upload the code into a JSFiddle and put the link

Comment: Why are you doing things like `tagMatch[i-1].textContent`? In the first case `i-1` will equal `-1` which will be an "array out of bounds" error

Comment: I have edited my post to include a link to JSFiddle.  I'm doing my search for <td> tags that equal "Offline" or "Partially Online".  In the cell order of the table, that hit at i will be the second cell, so I need to include i-1 to grab the name of the system, and i+1 to grab the notes associated with the system at position i.